# DataTable 1.10 - Disable row select event for certain columns

Tags: javascript, datatables

In the latest version (1.10) of DataTable , section is set in the table init

```
var table = $('#companies').DataTable( {
            language: { url: langUrl },
            select: true,
            ....
```

clicking on any cell will elect the row...
However , if the first column i used for sliding child row display, I would like to avoid the row selection ( this first column has a 'details-control' class..

With the old Datatable version , one's could do the following, using TableTools

```
"fnPreRowSelect": function ( e, nodes ) {
    if ( $(e.currentTarget).hasClass('details-control') ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

that's what I tested, but within the latest version, TableTools has been left over, and now using Select/Button is a recommended practice... 
anyone knows how to get the same behaviour with the new version ?

thanks for lights..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [select.selector](https://datatables.net/reference/option/select.selector) option or [select.selector()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/select.selector()) function.

Here is the [demo](http://live.datatables.net/pokopiju/1/edit).

```js
$(document).ready( function ()  {
                  
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    fixedColumns: {
      leftColumns: 1,
      rightColumns: 1
    },
    select: {
        style: 'single',
        info: false,
      selector: 'td:not(.status)'
    },
    columnDefs: [
      {
        targets: -1,
        className: "dt-body-center status"
      }
    ],
    scrollY:        "300px",
    scrollX:        true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging:         false,
    orderCellsTop: true,
    order: [[1, 'asc']],
    colReorder: {
      realtime: false,
    },
    autoWidth: false,
  });
} );
```

```css
body {
  font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.simon-toggle {
    width: 90px;
    height: 30px;
}

.simon-toggle-ignored, .simon-toggle-accepted, .simon-toggle-declined {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-left: 0.5px;
    margin-right: 0.5px;
}

.simon-toggle-ignored {
    background-color: grey;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

.simon-toggle-accepted {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.simon-toggle-declined {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.2/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.2/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.0/css/select.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.0/js/dataTables.select.js"></script>
    

        
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jenna Elliott</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>2008/11/28</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2012/12/02</td>
            <td>$4,525</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2012/08/06</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>2010/10/14</td>
            <td>$6,730</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>39</td>
            <td>2009/09/15</td>
            <td>$5,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sonya Frost</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2008/12/13</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jena Gaines</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2008/12/19</td>
            <td>$5,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2013/03/03</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Charde Marshall</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>2008/10/16</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2012/12/18</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>2010/03/17</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Michael Silva</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2012/11/27</td>
            <td>$3,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Paul Byrd</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2010/06/09</td>
            <td>$5,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Gloria Little</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2009/04/10</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Bradley Greer</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2012/10/13</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Dai Rios</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>2012/09/26</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2011/09/03</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Yuri Berry</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td>2009/06/25</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Caesar Vance</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2011/12/12</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Doris Wilder</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2010/09/20</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>2009/10/09</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>42</td>
            <td>2010/12/22</td>
            <td>$4,525</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>2010/11/14</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>2011/06/07</td>
            <td>$3,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ebony Grimes</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>48</td>
            <td>2010/03/11</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Russell Chavez</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>2011/08/14</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Michelle House</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2011/06/02</td>
            <td>$3,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Suki Burks</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>2009/10/22</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/05/07</td>
            <td>$6,730</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2008/10/26</td>
            <td>$6,730</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Martena Mccray</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/03/09</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Unity Butler</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/12/09</td>
            <td>$3,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/12/16</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2010/02/12</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>62</td>
            <td>2009/02/14</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2008/12/11</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>2008/09/26</td>
            <td>$5,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Miriam Weiss</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2011/02/03</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Bruno Nash</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>2011/05/03</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Odessa Jackson</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2009/08/19</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Thor Walton</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2013/08/11</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Finn Camacho</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/07/07</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Elton Baldwin</td>
            <td>Data Coordinator</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2012/04/09</td>
            <td>$6,730</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2010/01/04</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>56</td>
            <td>2012/06/01</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2013/02/01</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cara Stevens</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/12/06</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Hermione Butler</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2011/03/21</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Lael Greer</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2009/02/27</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2010/07/14</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Shad Decker</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/11/13</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Michael Bruce</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>2011/06/27</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Donna Snider</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/01/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It can be very handy to use the `createdRow` callback to conditionally add something like a `.no-select` class to the entire row, then use `selector: `tr:not(.no-select) td` to disable a subset of the rows. A `.no-select { opacity: 0.6; cursor: not-allowed; }` style in your CSS compliments that well.

Comment: Side note: this approach has the added benefit of keeping your select callback uncluttered.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply [**`deselect()`**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().deselect()) rows you not want to be selected :

```
table.on('select.dt', function(e, dt, type, indexes) {
  indexes.forEach(function(i) {
    if (table.row(i).nodes().to$().children(':first').hasClass('details-control')) {
      table.row(i).deselect();
    }    
  })      
});
```

It works with both single and multiple selects. Demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/snpekxff/**

Comment: thanks for your suggestion , however my goal is to avoid these cells from being used to 'select' the row...
in table.on('select'  , the row is already selected ...